# Calculate improper integral using contour

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm trying to calculate integral with contour method.
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{4x^2-\pi^2}\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
I checked the singularity points of function $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{4z^2-\pi^2}$ are $z=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$. So I made a contour: it begins from original point, along with the real axis, and not meet with point $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, then a semi-circle back to the negative part of real axis, and then not meet with point $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$, finally back to the original point.
The contour integration is:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon}+\int_{C_{\epsilon}}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon}^{R}+\int_{C_{R}}+\int_{-R}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon}+\int_{C_{\epsilon}'}=0
\end{equation}

I have proved the integration $\int_{C_{R}}\to0$ as $R\to+\infty$. But I can't handle the part $\int_{C_{\epsilon}}$ and $\int_{C_{\epsilon}'}$. I want to make Laurent expansion on the function near the point $z=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I'm not sure is it right. So would you please give me some help on the small part? Other contour methods are welcomed.

Comment: Without introducing the complex exponential, the original function as-is has no singularity. Would it not be easier to integrate that?

Comment: @NinadMunshi No idea to find the original function. I still prefer to calculate it in contour integration.

Comment: ...the original function is $\frac{\cos x}{4\pi^2-x^2}$. I never said to not use contour integration, go nuts. It's just this function has no singularities to worry about.

Comment: Just as a possible another approach (for example, for checking the answer)
$$I=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos x}{(x-\pi/2)(x+\pi/2)}dx=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\cos x\left(\frac1{x-\pi/2}-\frac1{x+\pi/2}\right)dx$$
$$=\frac1{2\pi}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(t+\pi/2)}tdt-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(t-\pi/2)}tdt\right)=-\,\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin t}tdt$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi The cosine would not vanish on any semicircle. It is easy to use the exponential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$This works. Let's even generalise it - why not? Let $a,b>0$ be fixed real numbers.

You want: $$J=\int_\Bbb R\frac{\cos x}{a^2x^2-b^2}\d x$$(with $a=2,b=\pi$). You suggest considering the function $f:H\to\Bbb C$ on the upper half plane, $z\mapsto\frac{e^{iz}}{a^2z^2-b^2}$. By the same contour you propose, we can show that: $$0=\int_{\Bbb R\setminus{[-\delta-b/a,\delta-b/a]\cup[-\delta+b/a,\delta+b/a]}}f(x)\d x+\oint_{\gamma_1}f(s)\d s+\oint_{\gamma_2}f(s)\d s$$Where $\delta>0$ has been fixed and $\gamma_1$ is a clockwise oriented semicircle of radius $\delta$ about $-b/a$ and $\gamma_2$ is a clockwise oriented semicircle of radius $\delta$ about $b/a$.

What to do? We want to think about the half-residue principle. When a meromorphic function has a simple pole, expansion in Laurent series reveals that the integral of all terms other than the residue is irrelevant as you go around such $\gamma$ whose radius shrinks. An alternative way: parametrising $\gamma_1=-b/a+\delta e^{it}$, notice you basically get an integrand of $\delta e^{it}f(s)=(s+b/a)\cdot f(s)$, so this is the expression to care about.

Substitute $s=z-b/a$ in $f(s)$ for $s\in\gamma_1$: $$f(s)=e^{-ib/a}\cdot\frac{e^{iz}}{(as-b)(as+b)}=\frac{e^{-ib/a}}{a}\cdot\frac{e^{iz}}{az-2b}\cdot\frac{1}{z}$$So it follows that $(s+b/a)f(s)\to-\frac{e^{-ib/a}}{2ab}$ as $s\to-b/a$. It follows by either the *half-residue principle* (easy proof by expanding in Laurent series) or an integral convergence theorem that: $$\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\oint_{\gamma_1}f(s)\d s=\pi i\cdot\frac{e^{-ib/a}}{2ab}$$Similarly: $$\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\oint_{\gamma_2}f(s)\d s=-\pi i\cdot\frac{e^{ib/a}}{2ab}$$Concluding: $$J=\frac{\pi i}{2ab}(e^{ib/a}-e^{-ib/a})=-\frac{\pi}{ab}\sin(b/a)$$

Comment: A great answer, you generalized it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I worked out this small part integral. According to Jordan's lemma(I haven't learned it before), the limits
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\to-\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{iz}}{4z^2-\pi^2}(z+\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{i}{4\pi}\quad\lim_{z\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{iz}}{4z^2-\pi^2}(z-\frac{\pi}{2})=
\frac{i}{4\pi}
\end{equation}
Applying Jordan's lemma,
\begin{equation}
\int_{C_{\epsilon}}+\int_{C_{\epsilon}'}=i(0-\pi)\frac{i}{2\pi}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
Then let $R\to+\infty$ and $\epsilon\to0+$ and take real part of the integration,
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{4x^2-\pi^2}=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}